# Is okay to have different solution to differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the following differential equation: 
$ydx - xdy - dx = 0$

Now, I could divide it by Integrating factor $x^2$ to get:

$(xdy - ydx)/(x^2) - dx/x^2 = 0$

Use the inspection rule to get:

$d(y/x) + dx/x^2 = 0$

Then Integrate this **exact differential equation** to get the answer:

$(y - 1)/x = c$

That's seems okay..

But what if I had divided it by $y^2$?

The solution I then get would be:

$d(x/y) + dx/y^2 = 0$

Is that completely fine to have different Integrating factors or should you always pick $x^2$?

Comment: The $y^2$ way does not work since $-\frac{dx}{y^2}$ is not $d(\frac{1}{y})$. So multiplying by $y^2$ does not give you an exact equation.

Comment: Could you explain it as an answer what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you found the integration factor $\frac{1}{x^2}$ using the typical way, although I didn't check. This gives a correct solution.

The $\frac{1}{y^2}$ won't work since the second one is not an exact equation. For it to be exact like the first one, you need
$$d(\frac{x}{y})-\frac{dy}{y^2}=0$$
whereas you have 
$$d(\frac{x}{y})-\frac{dx}{y^2}=0$$
which is not exact since the $\frac{dx}{y^2}$ term is not a differential.

And by the way, since this is a linear differential equation, it should have one solution. An alternative way to solve it is to use separation of variable:
$$y-1-x\frac{dy}{dx}=0\\
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y-1}\\
\ln |x|=\ln |y-1|+C\\
x=c (y-1)$$

**Edit:**
There is a different integration factor though, which is $\frac{1}{(y-1)^2}$. The integration factors are obtained by either 
$$\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{N}\tag1$$
or 
$$\frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}\tag2$$

They should give you the same result.

**Edit 2:**

First of all, a differential equation is exact if
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=0$$

If not, we can multiply by an integration factor if (1) only depends on $x$. In that case, the integration factor is $$e^{\int (1) dx} $$
where (1) means the expression in (1). Otherwise we check whether (2) depends only on $y$. If that is true, the integration factor is $$e^{\int (2) dx}$$ These steps give you an exact equation.

Comment: How can I know that $d(x/y) - dy/y^2$ is exact? I usually check the exactness through partially differentiating and see if $∂M/∂y = ∂N/∂x$ where M is the $dx$ part and N is $dy$ part.

Comment: @cpx:Then how did you get $d(y/x) - dx/x^2$ is exact? I thought you see that $dx/x^2=d(-1/x)$. This one is similar, just replace $x$ by $y$.

Comment: I didn't. The steps in textbook said that it was exact. So, I wondered why didn't we check whether it was exact or how can we tell it is exact?

Comment: @cpx: We can tell it is exact just by seeing that $dx/x^2=d(-1/x)$. And we don't need to check whether it is exact if we follow the procedures in my "edit" to find the integration factor. I will edit a little bit more.